# Exposed form block disappear when views has no results

Tags: views, theming

I created a view template for my website in which i put my exposed form block with twig tweak module. It works when there is at least 1 result. 
But when my view has no result, the exposed form disappear so i have to reload the page.

```
{#
/**
 * @file views-bootstrap-grid.html.twig
 * Default simple view template to display Bootstrap Grids.
 *
 *
 * - columns: Contains rows grouped by columns.
 * - rows: Contains a nested array of rows. Each row contains an array of
 *   columns.
 * - column_type: Contains a number (default Bootstrap grid system column type).
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
#}
{%
  set classes = [
    'views-view-grid',
  ]
%}
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
<div>
  <h1 class="text-center titreRecherche col-12">Nos formations</h1>
  <p class="text-center " style="letter-spacing: 5px;"> Découvrez toutes les formations proposées par le CFA <p>
</div>
<div id="{{ id }}" {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="sidebar sidebarView col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mt-3" >
----->  {{ render_block('formulaireexposerecherche_formationpage_1') }} <---------------
  </div>
    {% for key, row in rows -%}
      <div {{ row_attributes.addClass(options.row_class) }} >

        <div class="card cardViewRecherche" style="width: 18rem;">
          <h2 class="card-title text-center TypeDiplome"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 0.5rem; "></i>{{ view.style_plugin.getField(loop.index0, 'field_type_de_diplome') }}<i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 0.5rem; color: #f7ea48;"></i></h2>
            {{ drupal_field('field_type_de_diplome', 'taxonomy_term', tid) }}
          <h3 class="card-title text-center abreviationView">{{ view.style_plugin.getField(loop.index0, 'field_abreviation_recherche') }}</h3>
          {% set lienContenu = view.style_plugin.getField(loop.index0, 'view_node') %}
          <div class="card-img-top">{{ view.style_plugin.getField(loop.index0, 'field_image_principale') }}</div>
          <div class="card-body bodyRecherche text-center">
            <h3 class="card-title text-center">{{ view.style_plugin.getField(loop.index0, 'field_localisation') }}<i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" style="font-size: 1.4rem;"></i></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tested all the solutions i found on internet but nothing works.

Sorry, I'm beginner on drupal.

Thanks !!